# React setting an entire state with an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a state of FormData

`const [FormData, setFormData] = useState({}) as any;`

I have an object `cir` which contains many keys.

How to set the FormData with cir initially and later update with form?

```
Object.keys(cir).forEach((key) => {
      setFormData({ ...FormData, [key]: cir.key });
      console.log(key, cir[key]);
    });
```

```
const [FormData, setFormData] = useState({}) as any;
  const [Test, setTest] = useState<object>();
  // States-------States-------States-------States-------States-------States-------States-------States-------



// This is Working
  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...FormData, [name]: value });
  };

  // useEffect----------useEffect----------useEffect----------useEffect----------useEffect----------useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      navigate("/");
    }

    dispatch(getCIR(params._id));

    console.log(FormData);
  }, []);
  // useEffect----------useEffect----------useEffect----------useEffect----------useEffect----------useEffect

const setInitialFormData = () => {
 Object.keys(cir).forEach((key : string) => {

// This is not working. Why?????

  setFormData({ ...FormData, key: cir[key] });
});
}

if (isSuccess) {
  setInitialFormData();
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: I am getting the cir after a api call.

Comment: Try `setFormData(cir)` after your api call to set it as cir initially.

Comment: What do you mean by this is not working? Is there an error? Is your function not running? Or are you getting the incorrect data being set to the state?